# Understanding Spring Boot actuator `http.server.requests` metrics MAX attribute

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

can someone explain what does the MAX statistic refers to in the below response. I don't see it documented anywhere.

```
localhost:8081/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/myControllerMethod
```

Response:

```
{  
   "name":"http.server.requests",
   "description":null,
   "baseUnit":"milliseconds",
   "measurements":[  
      {  
         "statistic":"COUNT",
         "value":13
      },
      {  
         "statistic":"TOTAL_TIME",
         "value":57.430899
      },
      {  
         "statistic":"MAX",
         "value":0
      }
   ],
   "availableTags":[  
      {  
         "tag":"exception",
         "values":[  
            "None"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "tag":"method",
         "values":[  
            "GET"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "tag":"outcome",
         "values":[  
            "SUCCESS"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "tag":"status",
         "values":[  
            "200"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "tag":"commonTag",
         "values":[  
            "somePrefix"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the individual metrics by using `?tag=url:{endpoint_tag}` as defined in the response of the root `/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests` call. The details of the `measurements` values are;

- **COUNT:** Rate per second for calls.
- **TOTAL_TIME:** The sum of the times recorded. Reported in the monitoring system's base unit of time

> - **MAX:** The maximum amount recorded. When this represents a time, it is reported in the monitoring system's base unit of time.

As given [here](https://static.javadoc.io/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.6/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Statistic.html), also [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Statistic.java).

---

The discrepancies you are seeing is due to the presence of a timer. Meaning after some time currently defined `MAX` value for any tagged metric can be reset back to `0`. Can you add some new calls to `/myControllerMethod` then immediately do a call to `/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests` to see a non-zero `MAX` value for given tag?

This is due to the idea behind getting `MAX` metric for each smaller period. When you are seeing these metrics, you will be able to get an array of `MAX` values rather than a single value for a long period of time.

You can get to see this in action within Micrometer source code. There is a [`rotate()`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/1.2.x/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/distribution/TimeWindowMax.java#L117) method focused on resetting the `MAX` value to create above described behaviour.

You can see this is called for every [`poll()`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/1.2.x/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/distribution/TimeWindowMax.java#L89-L90) call, which is triggered every some period for metric gathering.

Comment: in my case `MAX` is always equal to zero, irrespective of the number of times the endpoint is invoked.

Comment: @RahulGupta how about how recent was it since you last called the endpoint? Can you check the `MAX` value just after calling the endpoint? Also confirm the change in `COUNT` when you call, maybe you a are calling `/metrics/http.server.requests` endpoint with wrong tag?

Comment: yeah I tried that too... but that also doesn't change anything.

Comment: @RahulGupta that is weird, I tested on my endpoints, the behaviour was like that, after some time from last call, the `MAX` goes to `0`... You are sure that `COUNT` gets incremented when you call but `MAX` stays `0` ?

Comment: I got the issue, since I had customised `@Timed` on my controller methods. I have not been looking into `/metrics/http.server.requests` endpoint but at  the custom metrics endpoint and there this problem of `MAX` occurs. When I disabled the custom endpoint, I see the `MAX` to be working as expected. Any idea on what needs to be done to make `MAX` work on customized `@Timed' annotations?

Comment: @RahulGupta what name did you give in your `@Timed` ? Can you pass the name of that as `tag` in your `/metrics/http.server.requests` call? It is a `name` tag rather than `uri` tag. I think all that stats go to that tag, rather than the endpoint itself maybe? Can you confirm this? If not I will test on my local also!

Comment: its quite weird but now `MAX` is working as expected without changing anything in the customized `@Timed`.  Thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score 3):

- **What does MAX represent**

MAX represents the maximum time taken to execute endpoint.

Analysis for `/user/asset/getAllAssets`

```
COUNT  TOTAL_TIME  MAX
5      115         17
6      122         17  (Execution Time = 122 - 115 = 17)
7      131         17  (Execution Time = 131 - 122 = 17)
8      187         56  (Execution Time = 187 - 131 = 56)  
9      204         56  From Now MAX will be 56 (Execution Time = 204 - 187 = 17)
```

---

- **Will MAX be 0 if we have less number of request (or 1 request) to the particular endpoint?**

No number of request for particular endPoint does not affect the MAX *(see Image from Spring Boot Admin)*

---

- **When MAX will be 0**

There is *[Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247185/spring-boot-actuator-max-property/57250638#57250638)* which set the value 0. When the endpoint is not being called or executed for sometime Timer sets MAX to 0. Here *approximate timer value is 2 minutes (120 seconds)*

*[DistributionStatisticConfig](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/distribution/DistributionStatisticConfig.java)*  has `.expiry(Duration.ofMinutes(2)).`
which sets some measurements to 0 if there is no request has been made in between expiry time or rotate time.

---

- **How I have determined the timer value?**

For that, I have taken 6 samples (executed the same endpoint for 6 times). For that, I have determined the *time difference between the time of calling the endpoint - time for when MAX set back to zero*

**[More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247185/spring-boot-actuator-max-property/57250638#57250638)**

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

[Document](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-docs/pull/101/files) has been updated.

> NOTE:
>
> - Max for basic `DistributionSummary` implementations such as `CumulativeDistributionSummary`, `StepDistributionSummary` is a time
>     window max (`TimeWindowMax`).
> - It means that its value is the maximum value during a time window.
> - If the time window ends, it'll be reset to 0 and a new time window starts again.
> - Time window size will be the step size of the meter registry unless expiry in `DistributionStatisticConfig` is set to other value
>     explicitly.

Comment: If you are wondering what is this awesome `Spring Boot Admin`, it's from [codecentric](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) and an excellent presentation can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ql1Gnz4L_-c).