# http_server_requests_seconds_max exact meaning in Micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

In Prometheus I've got 14 seconds for http_server_requests_seconds_max.

```
http_server_requests_seconds_max{exception="None",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/v1/**",} 14.3
```

Does this mean the total time for the request from the server to the client or does it only measure the time in the Spring container?
I'm also measuring the time inside spring to process the data and it only takes 2.5 seconds. 
What I want to know is if it is a problem in Spring or if it is because of a slow network.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the copy of Spring documentation at Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210709120836/https://docs.spring.io/spring-metrics/docs/current/public/prometheus) (or [current Micrometer.io page](https://docs.micrometer.io/micrometer/reference/implementations/prometheus.html)), when `@Timed` attribute is used on a function or a Controller, it produces the metrics `http_server_requests`.

> which by default contains dimensions for the HTTP status of the
> response, HTTP method, exception type if the request fails, and the
> pre-variable substitution parameterized endpoint URI.

The `http_server_requests_seconds_max` is then computed as explained [in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247185/spring-boot-actuator-max-property)

> public static final Statistic MAX
>
> The maximum amount recorded. When this represents a time, it is
> reported in the monitoring system's base unit of time.

In your case, it means that one of you endpoint in the range `/v1/**` (i.e. one of all of them) called a `@Timed` function that took 14sec to execute.

For more information you would need percentiles or histograms metrics. It may happen only once; usually at the first request wen cache need to be built or services needs to warm up.